# RapidMiner ExecuteProgram Operator Text Stream

Tags: java, input, stream, operator-keyword, rapidminer

I'm currently working with RapidMiner 6 and at the end of a process I have to pipe out the Data Set to a Java Program.

In the documentation says that a process like : "Write CSV -> Execute Program" will send the data set through the standard output to the program I'm executing, but my cuestion is: How can I know, in my Java program, when the data has been sent?

The current program just reads from the standard input and saves what was written as a csv file. The code is:

```
public class WakaMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inLine = in.nextLine();
    while(inLine != null){
        input.add(inLine);
        inLine = in.nextLine();
    }
    in.close();
    writeStream(input);
    System.out.println("Done: "+input.size()+" Inputs");
}

public static void writeStream(ArrayList<String> in) throws IOException{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("StreamWriteOutput.csv");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    for(int i = 0; i<in.size();i++){
        pw.println(in.get(i));
    }
    pw.close();
}}
```

I first thought " inLine != null " would work as it does while reading a text file, but it doesn't.

Do you know how can I do this?

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hasNextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) function

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inLine;
    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        if(in.nextLine() != null){
        inLine =   in.nextLine();
        input.add(inLine);
        }

    }
    in.close();
    //writeStream(input);
    System.out.println("Done: "+input.size()+" Inputs");
}
```